# Обработка ошибок SOAP Client PHP

Tags: php, soap

При обращении к SOAP серверу выводятся ошибки вида Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 787). ---> Input string was not in a correct format.
Как обрабатывать такие ошибки? Если бы был вывод header SOAPа можно было понять в чем дело, но что делать с этими цифрами?

Answer (score 1):

Первая цифра - номер строки, вторая цифра - номер колонки, в которой у Вас находится ошибка в отправленном xml.

Перепроверьте формирования xml-документа, вы где-то передаете не правильное значение какого-то параметра (вероятно, что передаваемое вами значение не соответствует ожидаемому типу).

Comment: Я понимаю, что это номер строки и колонки. Но где искать название того параметра, который не соответствует, как вывести этот параеметр? Меня интересует, как обработать ошибки, а не данная конкретная ошибка.